# How to set default value in function

Tags: flutter

I try to set default value in function:

```
bool isOnGoing([DateTime date = DateTime.now()]) {
    ...
}
```

But studio returns "Default values of an optional parameter must be constant".

How can I set default parameter in this case?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The syntax you use is correct, but as the error message says, the value has to be a compile time constant.

A compile time constant doesn't make sense for `DateTime.now()`.

As a workaround, you can use:

```
/// Returns `true` is still going on.
///
/// [date] the date to check.
///   as default value `DateTime.now()` is used 
///   if no value or `null` was passed.
bool isOnGoing([DateTime date]) {
    date ??= DateTime.now();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I use this syntax for now. I just curious - maybe there is another solution...

Comment: No, because of the constraint that the default value needs to be compile time const.

Answer (score 1):

When you have **multiple parameters** use like below

```
int findVolume(int length, int breadth, {int height = 4}) {
  return length*breadth*height;
}

void main() {
  var result = findVolume(2, 3);
  print(result);
  print("");
  //Overriding the default parameter
  var result2 = findVolume(1, 2, height: 5);
  print(result2);
}

*===== output ======*
24

10
```

If you use [ ] instead of { } to declare local variables in function,

```
int findVolume(int length, int breadth, [int height = 12]) {
  return length*breadth*height;
}

===== you can call like below ======
findVolume(3, 6);
findVolume(3, 6, 5);
```

All credits go to:- https://flutterrdart.com/dart-optional-default-parameters-function/

Comment: The question was not about it, but about DateTime default value which requires const modifier

Answer (score 1):

For function it's there, for class you may need .

```
class RemoteArticleRequest {
final String apiKey = defaultApiKey;
final String category;
final int page;
final int pageSize = requestPageSize;

const RemoteArticleRequest({required this.page, this.category = 'general'});
}
```